# How to read metadata of npz file without loading it into memory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to know if it is possible to know the shape of a disk saved numpy array without loading the array into memory. This is possible with .hdf5 files, but don't know if it is possible with .npz files.
Something like:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.arange(10000)
arr2 = np.arange(10000)

np.savez('tmp/my_arrays.npz', arr1 = arr1, arr2 = arr2)

my_arrays = np.load('tmp/my_arrays.npz')

# this loads the array into memory
my_arrays['arr1'].shape

# looking for something perhaps like
my_arrays.arr1.shape
```

Comment: `my_arrays['arr1']` does several things.  It identifies the `arr1.npy` file in the zip archive, and then does an `npy` load.  That load fetches a header that contains the shape and dtype info, and the bulk of the file which is the data-buffer.  By hacking the `np.load` code you might be able to load just the header.

Comment: I guess you could load the array as a memory-mapped array and inspect its shape: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.open_memmap.html#numpy.lib.format.open_memmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A npz-file is just a zip archive of arrays. It can be opened using [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) and than methods from the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html) can be used to extract only the header (shape,fortran_order,dtype).

**Example**

```
import zipfile
import numpy as np

def read_metadata(file_name):
    zip_file=zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, mode='r')
    arr_names=zip_file.namelist()

    metadata=[]
    for arr_name in arr_names:
        fp=zip_file.open(arr_name,"r")
        version=np.lib.format.read_magic(fp)

        if version[0]==1:
            shape,fortran_order,dtype=np.lib.format.read_array_header_1_0(fp)
        elif version[0]==2:
            shape,fortran_order,dtype=np.lib.format.read_array_header_2_0(fp)
        else:
            print("File format not detected!")
        metadata.append((arr_name,shape,fortran_order,dtype))
        fp.close()
    zip_file.close()
    return metadata

read_metadata('my_arrays.npz')
#[('arr1.npy', (10000,), False, dtype('int32')),
# ('arr2.npy', (10000,), False, dtype('int32'))]
```